# PHP Locale get country code

Tags: php, locale

I am currently getting a user's country in PHP using the following method;

```
Locale::getDisplayRegion($_SERVER[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE],'en')
```

This returns the countries name in text e.g. United States.

However, I want to return the abbreviated country code from the `$_SERVER[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE]` request rather than the full text name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) framework has a handy function for determining the preferred language based on the `Accept-Language` header:

https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1463
https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1498

Comment: A quick search turned up this article: http://www.dyeager.org/blog/2008/10/getting-browser-default-language-php.html

Comment: My issue here is if a user's language is en_GB they are in the UK but your solution would return GB as the country rather than UK. How can I do this?

Comment: By the way, have you tried `Locale::getRegion`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.getregion.php

Comment: If that function does what you need, you still have to parse out the individual language codes from the `Accept-Language` header for which you can use the code I linked in three comments earlier.

Comment: I have looked at `Locale::getRegion` but it returns GB for en_GB. Any ideas how to make this UK instead?

Comment: `Locale::getRegion` uses the ICU database to determine which country code belongs to which language. I'm afraid you will have to assemble your own database for language and country codes if you want a different behavior.

Comment: I took a look at the ICU data files, here is the one for en_GB: http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/source/data/region/en_GB.txt. As you can see, *United Kingdom* is associated with *GB* here. Below that there is a *CoutriesShort* section that has *UK* as well, but I don't think a PHP function exists to retrieve those values.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to use the abbreviated country code, you can use something as such.

$country = substr(locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']), -2);

This will result in producing "xx" in for the variable resulting in country code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Locale` class' `acceptFromHttp()` method along with the `parseLocale()` method to get the 2 character country code:

```php
$countryCode = Locale::parseLocale(Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))['region'];
// $countryCode would be "US" if the header locale was "en_US"
```

The [`acceptFromHttp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/locale.acceptfromhttp.php) method will take the server value and match it with what the locales available on the server. It is lenient so if it is not quite right it will correct when necessary then return a locale string.

The [`parseLocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/locale.parselocale.php) method will read a locale string and break it apart into an associative array. The "region" index is the country code.